# Obter o mínimo entre dois argumentos quando um envolve uma expressão com incógnitas

Tags: python, sympy

Tenho um sistema indefinido (24 incógnitas / 14 equações) de equações não-lineares, ao qual preciso obter solução através de um método numérico para sistemas não lineares, como o dos Gradientes Conjugados ou Newton Raphson, por ex. .
Estou a definir as variáveis não conhecidas com o Sympy, uma vez que depois também precisarei da matriz Jacobiana do Sistema, pelo que é conveniente em temros de obter as várias derivadas parciais.

Acontece que 3 das equações ds sistema são do tipo Incógnita - Min[Expressão com Incógnita, Valor Conhecido]. Nomeadamente (por ex.):

```
f1 - min(f1ref - k1 * (y1 - y1ref), f1max) = 0
```

onde:

f1 é incógnita, criada com:

```
f1 = symbols("f1", Real=True)
```

y1 é incógnita, criada com:

```
y1 = symbols("y1", Real=True)
f1ref = 1199; 
k1 = 1597.59;
y1ref = -3;
f1max = 2398;
```

Não consigo fazer o sistema registar as equações deste tipo pois como y1 é incógnita, ele não consegue determinar qual o valor mínimo entre os dois argumentos que estão a ser comparados.

Alguém sabe alguma forma de contornar este problema?
Dar um valor inicial a y1 não seria do interesse, precisamente por y1 ser uma incógnita para a qual busco solução após aplicar o método numérico iterativo.

Comment: Cara, tu tens que desenvolver um algoritmo para calcular o valor dessa incognita antes de usá-la. Se y1 é uma incógnita, tu deves isolá-la, calcular o valor, e então usá-la para conseguir o valor da próxima incógnita que tu precisas...

Comment: No contexto do problema não faz sentido, um vez que: y1 não seria a única variável para o qual teria de fazer isso, pois existem ainda mais duas equações iguais a essa, para y2 e y3, pelo que teria de resolver estas a priori também, mas essas variáveis y1, y2, y3 no sistema aparecem em expressões com outras incógnitas, pelo que não posso obtê-las primeiro antes.

Comment: Cara, e como tu resolve isso usando papel e caneta, então? Tem solução? Talvez tu precises postar em um site de matemática (como o https://math.stackexchange.com/ por exemplo)

Comment: O meu objetivo seria após o sistema conseguir interpretar essas equações, simplesmente resolver o sistema linear do tipo J(x) * R (x) = -F(x), onde J(x) é a Jacobiana do sitema, F(x) é a matriz com os coeficientes do sistema (é o sistema de equaçoes em matriz) e R (x) são os resíduos. A resolução passa por obter o vetor (x) = [y1, y2, y3, .... todas as variáveis] que dá um R(x) mínimo, defenindo como stop de iteração uma condição do tipo R(x)^2 < tolerância à escolha

Comment: Este processo anterior é o que faz ser possível resolver o sistema que inicialmente é não linear e indefinido (J(x) * R(x) = -F(x)  já é um sistema linear e definido)

Comment: e qual seria o enunciado da questão, o sistema e o metodo numerico que você usou pra resolver exatamente?